# Script to make an empty file on birthdate in shell

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have to make a script that, when run, will put an empty file named "Happy Birthday!!!" in the home directory on the user's birthday. The birthdays of users are stored in a file called "birthdays.data", one entry per line, where each line is: username month day.

> For eg:
>   alice Nov 3
>   bob Oct 10

I have an algorithm in mind but I am not sure how can I implement it or if it is correct. My algorithm is something like this

```
today=$(date)
while not end of file birthdays.data
do
  read from file  NAME DATE
  if today=DATE then
    cd home
    touch "Happy Birthday!!!"     
  fi
done
```

Any idea if my algorithm is correct or how can I implement it in a code? As I am little bit new to shell scripting syntax.

Comment: You'd better use the full path to touch. By the way, don't you think that employing some advanced languages like Python would better and easier do the job?

Comment: I am forced to use unix and sh shell.

Comment: Then you better quote or you will end up with two files `'Happy'` and `'Birthday!!!'` (PS. there is no `endif` or `endwhile` in POSIX shell, it is `fi` and `done`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format today's date to match the format in the input file:

```
today=$(date '+%b %e')
```

Another non-trivial point is getting the home path of a user. If all the user homes are consistently in `/home`, then this can be as simple as:

```
userdir="/home/$username"
```

Otherwise, here's another way:

```
userdir=$(sudo -u "$user" bash -c 'echo $HOME')
```

The rest is getting the Bash syntax right:

```
today=$(date '+%b %e')
while IFS= read username date; do
  if [ "$today" = "$date" ]; then
    userdir="/home/$username"
    touch "$userdir"/'Happy Birthday!!!'
  fi
done < birthdays.data
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your input file is the same as shown, you can do it with GNU `awk` and `parallel`

```
awk -v m=$(date +%b) -v d=$(date +%d) 'm==$2&&d==$3{print $1}' birthdays.data |\
    parallel --dry-run touch /home/{}/Happy\ Birthday\!\!\!
```

Remove the `--dry-run` to actually create the file, you might also want to elevate your privilege by adding a `sudo` in front of `touch` to enable creating files inside other user's home directory

**Explaination**

- `-v m=$(date +%b)` and `-v d=$(date +%d)` passes the month and day value of today to awk
- `m==$2&&d==$3{print $1}` prints out user's name if that row contains the same date as today